Ubuntu Studio Installer won't uninstall/remove packages from Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I used the Ubuntu Studio Installer to install Ubuntu Studio on top of my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS OS to try it out as the Ubuntu Studio website made it sound like I could easily uninstall using the Ubuntu Studio Installer it if it didn't meet my needs.  I didn't realize that it would install so many applications, most of which I do not need along with duplicates of applications I already had installed, so I tried to uninstall packages by unchecking them in the Ubuntu Studio Installer. It then asked for authentication to remove the packages, however after providing authentication the Ubuntu Studio Installer just looped back to packages screen without uninstalling/removing anything. I've rebooted my computer and tried doing the same process several times now with no success.
I was deceived into thinking that uninstalling Ubuntu Studio would be a painless process and I stupidly did not back up my system before installing it, now I'm regretting it. If anyone has experience with successfully uninstalling Ubuntu Studio packages from Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, please help.

on my Ubuntu 24.04 I just installed  Ubuntu Studio ... never heard of it before ... seems to run OK using it I installed a couple of packages ... yes after clicking checkmark widgets do  install the packages next time I launched Studio it took me back to same UI ... evidently since the install completed I just hit  Close  ... I would guess its behavior is OK ... it appears Studio is simple a UI to perform same actions I typically execute manually from a terminal ... NOTE the packages it installs are real it is simply a different way to install or remove them

Please specify in your question above which route to a solution you want to take: Fast-fix-it-now, or slower-but-learning. Gurus here can do either. Also please add a list of the applications, clearly showing which are dupes (both unwanted), dupes (want to keep one), and non-dupes (unwanted).

Never mind, I figured out a workaround.
While I could not get the Ubuntu Studio Installer GUI to work, I found I was able to uninstall the packages in the terminal by using sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove [package-name]
